Using forward differencing on image collection containing masked pixels
I'm interested in obtaining the time difference between each observation in an image collection. This can be calculated as the DoY difference between each subsequence image in the image collection. The proper method to do this seems to be forward differencing, which works great. When the collection contains masked pixels (cloud masked), the array forward differencing return the difference between the time nearest two unmasked pixels. This is also great and exactly the desired behavior. However, now the final array image contains different lengths arrays and I can't tell which difference belong to which image. Is there a different work around or a way to convert this back into a collection with the DoY difference? Here is a code example
var sentinel2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED');
var sf = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.47555371521855, 37.76884708376152]);
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("B.*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

var s2 = sentinel2
    .filterBounds(sf)
    .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-04-30')
    .map(maskS2clouds)
    
Map.addLayer(s2,null,'original collection (masked)')

var withDoys = s2.map(function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B8']).rename('ndvi');
  var date = image.date();
  var doy = date.getRelative('day', 'year');
  var time = image.metadata('system:time_start');
  var doyImage = ee.Image(doy)
      .rename('doy')
      .int();
  return ndvi.addBands(doyImage).addBands(time)
      .clip(image.geometry()); // Appropriate use of clip.
});

var array = withDoys.toArray();
var timeAxis = 0;
var bandAxis = 1;

var subtract = function(array) {
  var time = array.arraySlice(bandAxis, -1);
  var sorted = array.arraySort(time);
  var doy = sorted.arraySlice(bandAxis, -2, -1);
  var left = doy.arraySlice(timeAxis, 1);
  var right = doy.arraySlice(timeAxis, 0, -1);
  var dif = right.subtract(left)
  return dif;
};

var DOYdifference = subtract(array);
Map.addLayer(DOYdifference,null,'different length array image')


You can pair up the original images with your differences using the time.
var differenceCollection = s2.map(function (image) {
  var arrayTime = array.arraySlice(bandAxis, -1)
  var timeMask = arrayTime
    .arraySlice(timeAxis, 0, -1) // Drop last time - will not have a difference
    .eq(image.getNumber('system:time_start'))
    .arrayProject([timeAxis])
  var maskedDifference = DOYdifference
    .arrayProject([timeAxis])
    .arrayMask(timeMask)
  var difference = maskedDifference
    .updateMask(maskedDifference.arrayLength(timeAxis))
    .arrayFlatten([['difference']])
  return image.addBands(difference)
})

Map.addLayer(differenceCollection, null, 'collection with difference')

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2a972c49f8b68d0987253236af481c38

This is brilliant! I was trying to figure out how to pair them using time but I gave up and settled to an iterative workaround using first not Null reducer. This time mask is the neat solution I was looking for, thank you @Daniel Wiell!

I’m happy it worked out!
